# Scanner nextInt() inside a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

Class code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int d = in.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                row.add(in.nextInt());
            }

            rows.add(row);
        }

        int q = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            System.out.println("test");
            int x = in.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("test2");
            int y = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("I dont get it");
            try {
                System.out.println(rows.get(x - 1).get(y - 1));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this imput

```
5
5 41 77 74 22 44
1 12
4 37 34 36 52
0
3 20 22 33
5
1 3
3 4
3 1
4 3
5 5
```

Result

```
74
52
37
ERROR!
ERROR!
```

I don't understand how nextInt() works in the last loop. Why do the lines "I dont get it", "test", "test2" never get printed?

Why is the try block executed at the end of the loop and not during the loop?

How could the stdout print 4 results at once?

Please help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is expected and what it producing?

Comment: This seems to be a debugging issue. I don't know what the expected output is, but it might help debugging each value after reading it in. I simulated this [**in this ideone-link**](https://ideone.com/NTb5U7) by printing every value you read from STDIN to STDOUT. Please provide the expected behavior and output so we can help you better, but perhaps this output already helps you determining the issue? PS: Output is different than you describe. Did you correctly compile and re-run your code.. :S

Comment: Of course the "missing" prints aren't missing, you probably forget to recompile your code correctly. Delete the class file, rebuild and re-run.

Comment: I cant see any issue with provided input.. compile again and check

Comment: This problem can't be reproduce anymore, it would seems you are using an incorrect build. And you really should add some instruction for the user to input...

Comment: this is what iam getting `enter something
2
1
1
1
1
1
test
1
test21
I dont get it
1`

Comment: The output is fine. The code is working. My question is why the results are being printed all at once instead of one by one as in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see below output with your input.

```
test
test2I dont get it
74
test
test2I dont get it
52
test
test2I dont get it
37
test
test2I dont get it
ERROR!
test
test2I dont get it
ERROR!
```

Just remove your .class and compile again and check.

Comment: Yeah, it was a problem with IDE I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Input

```
Output array   --> rows=[[41, 77, 74, 22, 44], [12], [37, 34, 36, 52], [], [20, 22, 33]]
```

In the first three iterations its printing

```
rows[0][2]=74
rows[2][3]=52
rows[2][0]=37
rows[3][2]=Error
```

-->because in your output array third index is an empty array [] ,there is nothing in the second position